# Problems adding Ads. Incompatibility between android support v4 and v7?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, admob, google-play-services, android-support-library

I have an application that uses **analytics and Theme.AppCompat.Dialog**, so, I need **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat**

The app is works.

Now, I want to add google ads.
The "package nuget : Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads" includes **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4**
 I did another test project and it works.

But, when I add this to my real project, I can not build the app.

I have this error: **"java.exe" exited with code 1.**
In the output:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2118,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**I read everything I have seen in the forum related to that error but I have not fixed. Any advice?**

Thanks.[image]

Comment: hello @ephramd, I have the same issue than you. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

@Fran_gg7
Yes!I found the real original problem and the solution.

The problem is ProGuard. If you have active ProGuard for some reason it does not like.
In my case if I disabled ProGuard the project works perfectly.
But ProGuard should be active by weight reduction in the apk, code obfuscation etc ...

**1.** On your Android project you must create a file: **proguard.txt**

And write this code:

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}

# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable Creators to not get stripped
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

# Needed when building against pre-Marshmallow SDK.
-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

# Keep metadata about included modules.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.** {
  public <fields>;
}

# Keep the implementation of the flags api for google-play-services-flags

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl {
  public <fields>; public <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

2. In the properties of the new file mark Build Action "ProguardConfiguration".
   [image]